# Wrong result when Calculating Difference in Time

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, codeigniter, datetime

I am writing a PHP function that calculates the difference the current time and a timestamp (eg: 2011-10-21 11:16:00) which is retrieved from a mySQL database table.

**Problem:**
The calculated time difference seems to be off by 6 hours! I checked through the code and I cant figure out why a timestamp made a few minutes ago result in a time difference of 6 hours! However when I set the variable `$datetime_now` to a specific value, the calculated time difference is correct! Any help to point me in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

**PHP Code:**

```
$datetime_now = new DateTime;
$datetime_post = new DateTime($results[$key]['post_timestamp']); //ie. 2011-10-21 11:16:00
$interval = $datetime_now->diff($datetime_post);
$hours = $interval->format('%h');
```

**Additional Info:**

I am running the web server (XAMPP package) on a local machine, and accessing the webpage from the same system.

Comment: what is your timezone? MySQL is storing timestamp fields in different timezone then your physical timezone ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timezones, I'm guessing you're GMT-6?  Correct this by using UTC for all of your transactions, then at the last stage making a conversion to local time.  Check your server locale settings and I bet you they will be different from where you're living.

Comment: I am in Boston, is the timezone UTC/GMT -5 hours? the error is 6hrs though.. let me check my server settings, do i find them under apache settings, or is there one under PHP, or MYSQL??

Comment: What kind of hosting server are you running?  Linux/Windows?  Do you have terminal access?

Comment: I'm running XAMPP in Windows on my laptop. My laptop and I are in Boston.

Comment: @Nyxynyx - Is it GMT -6 if you factor in daylight saving?